# Configuring Nginx as a proxy for a Vapor API

Tags: macos, nginx, vapor

'm pretty stuck after a few days of trying to get this working and I could use some help.

I have a vapor API that works fine. I created a route and can access it from http://localhost:8080/backend/returnA in a browser on the server. It returns some JSON.

Where I'm stuck is in trying to configure Nginx to server as a proxy. Can anyone help me understand how the http://localhost:8080/backend/returnA URL translates into a working URL accessible from the LAN?

I'm pretty confused as the Nginx.conf asks for a root URL but I don't know what to put in. If I leave it blank it defaults to /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.6/html/backend/returnA/index.html which obviously won't work. If I set it to the public folder in the Vapor app directory this also doesn't work. In both instances I get a "No such file or directory".

I've gone through countless Nginx conf settings found online, tried adding a proxy location, nothing works. Trying http://172.16.1.25/backend/returnA/ always returns a 404 from the Nginx server.

How do I point Nginx to my Vapor route when it's not serving a static file like index.html, and instead retuning JSON?

Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the config, edited to include Thanh's code, old location commented out:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

    http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]       "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;

    server {
    server_name 172.16.1.25;
    listen       80  default_server;

    root /Users/localadmin/Developer/server/MedicapAPI/Public/;

    # location @proxy {
    #    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #    proxy_pass_header Server;
    #    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #    proxy_pass_header Server;
    #    proxy_connect_timeout 3s;
    #    proxy_read_timeout 10s;
    # }

    location  / {
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }    
    }
        include servers/*;
    }
```

Comment: can you share the content of `nginx.conf` file which you have tried here ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed now.

Comment: pls check answer @rougement, just edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this :

```
listen       80  default_server;
server_name 172.16.1.25; #ip address of server
```

it will catch all server blokck and:

```
location  / {
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

It will be `proxy_pass` to application which is running in port 8080

Comment: Hi! I made the changes you suggested but I now get a 502 Bad Gateway error. Console says  [error] 14764#0: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.1.10, server: localhost, request: "GET /backend/returnA/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://localhost/backend/returnA/", host: "172.16.1.25"

Comment: change to  `server_name 172.16.1.25;` and check again

Comment: I still get a 502 error, console says "1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream" and "kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream". Thanks for helping, by the way. I appreciate it.

Comment: `proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/; ` no `https`, its just `http://`, re-check your configuration.

Comment: I'm new to this site. Do you mean the little green check? If so, already done and thanks again. I've been working on this for days and getting nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
server {
    #server_name  mysite.com;
    listen   80;

    error_log   /var/log/mysite.com_error.log warn;
    access_log  /var/log/mysite.com.ru_access.log;

    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location / {
        # redirect all traffic to localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        # enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        # prevents 502 bad gateway error
        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;

        reset_timedout_connection on;

        tcp_nodelay on;
    }

    # Give direct access to Public files of your app instead of using FileMiddleware
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml|html|mp4|pdf)$ {
        access_log        off;
        expires           30d;
        root /path/to/your/app/Public;
    }
}
```

This is my working example.

For production I suggest you to use SSL certificate e.g. from LetsEncrypt, replace listen port to 443 and add the following configuration lines after listen line:

```
ssl on;
ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH';
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
```

That's it, now you're ready for production!